# Rails time_zone_select DST support?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I'm building an event app that allows the users to create an event and I've noticed when I use time_zone_selects in a form builder it doesn't use DST automatically when rendering the options.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the helper method dst for this specific purpose: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/dst%3F

Comment: this doesn't answer my question. the time_zone_select uses the method `time_zone_options_for_select` to generate the options needed for the select input. The values in here are not aware of DST and this is the problem I am dealing with because if DST is needed the values don't change